# Download the text only (and not the images) from a web page with urllib in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm parsing web pages for data using Python with urllib.request.Request('url here', headers).  Unfortunately the file sizes seem very large and I believe the images etc are downloading in the text file when saving.  Using urllib, is there a way to only request/download the text.

Comment: The images will only download if they are embedded in the HTML, which is very uncommon. Maybe the pages are just large?

Comment: you can easily use beautiful soup and extract only text like this:  soup.get_text())

Comment: A useful diagnostic step might be to open your text file and see exactly what data it's saving.

Comment: Very true: you can save the content of the html and see if it is that big.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, much appreciated.  Being familiar with the data I'm quite sure more is being downloaded than needed.  As an example in Autohotkey it would download as 300kb, however here it's 1,300kb.  So a few thousand downloads a day, I would imagine take a toll on speed and the websites server.  Downloaded html, was 2.79mb, so I'm at a loss there.   I don't have a problem using beautiful soup, but was hoping to minimize the size on the front end and just use RegEx to get the text

Comment: Do you have an [mcve] ?